# Is there a way to auto-complete schema URIs?

Tags: android, eclipse, autocomplete

Today I learned how to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to auto-complete attributes, is there a way to do the same with schema URIs like `http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android`?

Currently, I am just copying and pasting them from examples like this...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".AnimatedActivity" >
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: If you are using Eclipse and the ADT, those should be automatically added for you as soon as you create the resource file.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yeah, I'm using both, but it doesn't do that...

Comment: You're problably creating a raw XML file, if it's the case, you should choose a new file called "Android XML [Layout, Values] file", cause these ones will have thoses Uris already declared.

Comment: And the XML file will need that URI only for the root item. All is automatic. *File > New > Others > Android > Android XML xxx File*, where *xxx* could be *Layout* / *Values*.